# How to set defaultValue after some delay on react select with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-hook-form

I am using react-select dropdown with react-hook-form library. I am calling an api to get defaultValue for react-select. Initially dropdown was not able to prepopulate the defaultValue. So i found a workaround for that and re render the whole JSX when i get data from api.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveData)}>
{!countryValue && (
      <Controller
        name="country"
        control={control}
        render={({ onChange, value, ref }) => (
          <Select
            options={country}
            value={country.find((c) => c.value === value)}
            onChange={(val) => onChange(val.value)}
          />
        )}
        rules={{ required: true }}
      />
    )}
    {countryValue && (
      <Controller
        name="country"
        control={control}
        render={({ onChange, value, ref }) => (
          <Select
            options={country}
            value={country.find((c) => c.value === value)}
            onChange={(val) => onChange(val.value)}
            defaultValue={country.find((c) => c.value === countryValue)}
          />
        )}
        rules={{ required: true }}
      />
    )}
{errors.country && <div>Field is rquired</div>}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
```

I put a condition on countryValue that when component get the value of countryValue it render the whole dropdown.

But when i submit the form with the same defaultValue hook form gives an error of country field as undefined.

I have created a sandbox for this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-with-react-hook-form-sc2xz

How can solve this issue. Is their any workaround.

Comment: can you post your expected output and explain a little more about what are you trying to do?

Comment: @akhtarvahid I want to set the defaultValue of the dropdown to india when api call is complete. And want to get only the value of the dropdwon when user submit the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that instead of recreating a new component to give it a default value, you should set the value on the existing component directly when you have it.

For that you can use `setValue` which you get from `useForm()` returned object.

Here is that part of the code:

```js
  const { handleSubmit, control, errors, setValue } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setValue("country", "India");
    }, 2000);
  }, [setValue]);
```

And [here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-with-react-hook-form-forked-fdlti?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1):

a great question, but it looks like you're doing it a little bit messy,
you're passing the countries object to Select component and you're filtering it again in the `value` and `onChange` props **(Why, i can't figure out?)**,

first you need to define a `defaultValue` for your Select component, but you cannot use both (`defaultValue` and `value`) in the same place, to do that use the Controller to set a default value for you you have already defined in countryValue state:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

let country = [
  { label: "Bangladesh", value: "Bangladesh" },
  { label: "India", value: "India" },
  { label: "China", value: "China" },
  { label: "Finland", value: "Finland" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [countryValue, setCountryValue] = useState({
    label: "India",
    value: "India"
  });
  const { handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCountryValue("India");
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("errors", errors);
  }, [errors]);

  const saveData = (form_data) => {
    console.log("form_data", form_data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(saveData)}>
        <Controller
          name="country"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={countryValue}
          render={({ onChange, value, ref }) => (
            <Select
              options={country}
              value={value}
              onChange={(val) => onChange(val)}
            />
          )}
          rules={{ required: true }}
        />

        {errors.country && <div>Field is rquired</div>}
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I managed like this

```js
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
const [defaultCategory, setDefaultCategory] = useState(null);
    
useEffect(() => {
    if(formAction === 'UPDATE') {
        setDefaultCategory(categories.find(element => element.value === data.category_id));
    }
}, [categories]);

<Controller
        control={control}
        name="category_id"
        render={({
            field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
        }) =>  {
            return(
                <Select
                    value={defaultCategory}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    options={categories}
                    placeholder="Select a category"
                    defaultOptions={true}
                    onChange={(val) => {
                        setDefaultCategory(val);
                        onChange(val);
                    }}
                    isSearchable={false}
                    className="
                        shadow-sm
                        focus:ring-indigo-500
                        focus:border-indigo-500
                        block
                        max-w-full
                        text-md
                        border-gray-300
                        rounded-md
                    "
                />
            );
        }}
    />                                                             />
```